# Why my playwright python code does not locate 'input'?

Tags: python, web-scraping, playwright, playwright-python

I'm trying to locate 'input' and fill some value, but the locator does not work properly.

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
from nested_lookup import nested_lookup

#Binance

with sync_playwright() as pw:
    browser = pw.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    context = browser.new_context(viewport={"width": 1920, "height": 1080})
    page = context.new_page()

    url = 'https://www.rootdata.com/Fundraising'

    page.goto(url)
    page.wait_for_timeout(3000)

    input_element = page.locator('input[id="input-1723"]')
    input_element.fill('Any Value')
```

I would like to know how should I fix the code to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Which input are you trying to type into? `document.querySelectorAll('input[id^="input-"]')` returns 8, with different numbers other than the one you picked.

Answer (score 0):

Because your inputs have dynamic IDs

```py
from playwright.sync_api import Page


def test_example(page: Page) -> None:
    page.goto("https://www.rootdata.com/Fundraising")
    page.get_by_role("textbox", name="Search").click()
```

Read some Playwright [locator docs](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/locators#locating-elements) to see their suggestions for locating elements.

> We recommend prioritizing role locators to locate elements, as it is
> the closest way to how users and assistive technology perceive the
> page.